# Tokenizing input file into linked list

Tags: c, string, pointers, linked-list, tokenize

I'm attempting to *tokenize* an input file and store its individual words within a linked list organized by word count. I've been struggling with storing the tokenized string into a node, and am struggling to understand what is incorrect in my `tokenizing/inserting` process. Currently, when printing the stored strings out, the first letter of each string is truncated off, and there is seemingly random garbage and the end of each string. I have tried the following to fix my error:

1. Null-terminating each string after tokenization (I've left that in
   my program as it appears to be correct)
2. Using `strncpy()` instead of `new_word->str = str;`
3. Passing a pointer to the tokenized string to my insert function,
   instead of just passing the string itself.

Below is my *code*:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <strings.h>

typedef struct word{ 
    int length; 
    char *str; 
    struct word *left;
    struct word *right; 
    struct word *down;
}word;


void print_list(word **head){ 

    word *temp_traverse = *head;
    word *temp_down;

    for( ; temp_traverse!=NULL; temp_traverse = temp_traverse->right){ 
        temp_down = temp_traverse;
        for( ; temp_down!=NULL; temp_down = temp_down->down){ 
            printf("Count: %d, String: %s\n", temp_down->length, temp_down->str);
        }
    }

}


int is_empty(word **head, word **tail){ 

    if((*head == NULL)||(*tail == NULL))
        return 1;

    return 0;
}

void insert(word **head, word **tail, word *new_word){ 

    if(is_empty(head, tail)){
        (*head) = new_word; 
        (*tail) = new_word;
        return;
    }

    if((new_word->length)<((*head)->length)){ 
        new_word->right = (*head);
        (*head)->left = new_word;
        (*head) = new_word;
        return;
    }

    word *temp = *head;

    while(((temp->right)!=NULL) && ((temp->length)<(new_word->length))) 
        temp = temp->right;

    if((temp->length) == (new_word->length)){
        while(temp->down != NULL)
            temp = temp->down;
        temp->down = new_word;
        return;
    }

    if(temp->right == NULL){
        word* last = (*tail);
        last->right = new_word;
        new_word->left = last; 
        (*tail) = new_word;
        return;
    }

    word* next = temp->right;
    temp->right = new_word;
    next->left = new_word; 
    new_word->left = temp; 
    new_word->right = next;

    return;
}

void create(word **head, word **tail, char **str){ 

    word *new_word = (word*)malloc(sizeof(word));
    int length = strlen(*str);

    if(new_word == NULL){
            fprintf(stderr, "Error creating a new word node.\n");
            exit(0);
        }

    new_word->str = (char*)malloc(sizeof(*str));
    strncpy(new_word->str, *str, length);
    //new_word->str = *str;
    new_word->length = length;
    printf("%s ", new_word->str); //test print

    new_word->left = NULL;
    new_word->right = NULL;
    new_word->down = NULL;

    insert(head, tail, new_word);

    return;
}


void tokenize(word **head, word **tail, char words_buffer[]){ 

    char *cur; 

    cur = strtok(words_buffer, " .,;()\t\r\v\f\n");

    *cur++ = '\0';
    create(head, tail, &cur);

    /* tokenize the next string and reset the "duplicate" variable */
    while((cur = strtok(NULL, " .,;()\t\r\v\f\n")) != NULL){
        //cur = strtok(NULL, " .,;()\t\r\v\f\n"); 
        *cur++ = '\0';      
        if(cur){
            create(head, tail, &cur);
        }
    }

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){ 

    FILE *fp;
    word *head = NULL; 
    word *tail = NULL;

    /*if(argc<3){
        printf("Failure: not enough arguments");
        return -1; 
    }*/

    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    char words_buffer[ftell(fp)+1];
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);

    if(fp==NULL){
        printf("Failure: unreadable file");
        return -1;
    }

    while(fgets(words_buffer, sizeof(words_buffer), fp)){
            if(strlen(words_buffer)>1)
                tokenize(&head, &tail, words_buffer);
    }

    //print_list(&head);

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

I've left my test string printing for your reference. You will also notice that I don't use `print_list` right now, as I have yet to store strings correctly.

Because of the garbage at the end, I am assuming I am either incorrectly using the pointer to the string, or am `malloc()`ing too much space. As for the truncation, I'm not sure, but I presume it is related to my `*cur++ = '\0';` line.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks for taking the time to take a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not copying the whole string with your `strncpy()`.

In fact, you are copying one character too few when you obtain the length with:

`int length = strlen(*str);`

As stated in the `strncpy()` manpage:

> Warning: If there is no null byte among the first n bytes of src, the string placed in dest will not be null-terminated.

So make sure that when you use functions operating on null-terminated strings, such as most of the standard library `str*()` functions, that you account for the `'\0'` terminator with:

`int length = strlen(*str) + 1;`

Also, as an aside, the `void *` returned by `malloc()` is implicitly converted to any object pointer type, so instead of:

`word *new_word = (word*)malloc(sizeof(word));`

you should simply use:

`word *new_word = malloc(sizeof(word));`

or even better:

`word *new_word = malloc(sizeof *new_word);`

to avoid errors caused by changing the pointer type in the declaration but not the `malloc()` call.

The `sizeof` operator doesn't evaluate non-variable-length array expressions, so this is a much more reliable way to obtain an object's size.

**EDIT**

As to the first character of each string missing, I would assume that is due to:

```
*cur++ = '\0';
```

as that just uselessly sets `cur[0]` to `'\0'`, and then increments the pointer; the string now starts at the second letter of your word.

Comment: Hi Joey, thanks for addressing both questions correctly. A follow-up to your fixes: now that I have implemented them, my program crashes after reading the first two strings, or fails to create a new node. Is this an issue with my lack of use of any free() in my code? Thanks

Comment: When I test your code, I don't get that behavior; all the words are printed out fine. Could you post the text file that crashes it? Are you sure you removed both `*cur++ = '\0';` lines?

Comment: I've uploaded it here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-4DUXPoTX3qN2JsMGt5Rnc3Ync

Comment: That text file works fine for me; double check that you have removed both `*cur++ = '\0';` lines. Also, lack of `free()` would not crash you unless you ran out of memory, so that is unlikely to be the issue.

Comment: Strange, I am certain I have removed both, yet the program continues to crash. I have run the code 100s of times today on a laptop with ~2GB of free space, is it possible that I have run out then? *Edit*: I deleted the third line of the input file and that eliminated the issue, it appears that my tokenizing function incorrectly handles single-string lines.

Comment: This is your code with my suggested edits (apart from the `malloc()` one, which would not affect this issue): http://pb.gehidore.net/AqX9.c Does this code still crash for you?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes it does crash my system. I'm using the newest gcc compiler on Windows, if that's of use.

Comment: Hm, I suppose it is possible you are out of memory (unlikely, but I have no other theories). All I can suggest is try a reboot, then attempt it again.

Comment: Will do, and I will also try it on a Linux system tomorrow. Many thanks for the fast replies and useful information!

Comment: Hi Joey, just wanted to follow: your advice worked well, I was just seg-faulting because of a missing "if" statement in my tokenizing function. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem! Just to let you know, you should mark the answer as accepted once the problem has been solved so others can find it :)